# jQuery mobile touch - repeat an event when held/hold

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, touch

I have the following function, which works great on a single press :

```
$('.ele').on('taphold', function () {
   var data_max = $(this).closest('.value').attr('data-max');
   var current = $(this).closest('.value').find('input');

   var newVal = parseInt(current.val()) + 1;

   if (newVal <= data_max) {
       current.val(newVal);
   }
});
```

However, what I would like to do, is re-run this for as long as the user keeps .ele pressed down.

I've found a couple of libraries that use onmousedown and up to good effect with a mouse, but this doesn't work with touch.

Any recommendations?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me nicely, looping as expected. Original script is here http://download.remysharp.com/mousehold.js

My edited version, changing bindings to the jquery mobile ones.

```
jQuery.fn.mousehold = function(timeout, f) {
if (timeout && typeof timeout == 'function') {
    f = timeout;
    timeout = 100;
}
if (f && typeof f == 'function') {
    var timer = 0;
    var fireStep = 0;
    return this.each(function() {
        jQuery(this).on("vmousedown", function() {
            fireStep = 1;
            var ctr = 0;
            var t = this;
            timer = setInterval(function() {
                ctr++;
                f.call(t, ctr);
                fireStep = 2;
            }, timeout);
        })

        clearMousehold = function() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            if (fireStep == 1) f.call(this, 1);
            fireStep = 0;
        }

        jQuery(this).on("vmouseout", clearMousehold);
        jQuery(this).on("vmouseup", clearMousehold);
    })
}
```

}